# color coded revision history

Tags: diff, versioning, revision-history

Is there any tool or code that can basically compare multiple previous versions of the same file and give kind of a "combined" diff with perhaps color coding representing each revision?

Comment: By "multiple ... versions", do you mean "more than 2 versions, or more than 1 parent and 2 sibling versions"? If so, check out my `difdef` utility (https://github.com/Quuxplusone/difdef). I'd like to see the existing answers updated as to whether they support N>3 versions, or if people are just naming graphical diff tools at random based on the assumption that you don't already know about diff/kdiff3/opendiff/filemerge.

Comment: Hi, yes indeed I was looking for something that can color-code multiple revisions (>10 even maybe?) so yes your suggestion is the only one that addresses this! I will check out your code!

Answer (score 2):

There are many:

- SVN, comparing with the Diff
  [image]
- WinMerge 
  [image]
- Bitbucket

[image]

- Github

Choose the one you prefer

Comment: I was actually wondering if there was any tool that can show revisions coded from not just two versions, but more...

Comment: yes, you can do this. But must look each commit you've done and compare to other version

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has a same annotate function in the `Team` context menu.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `Beyond Compare`. It's a nice tool to compare files, it shows differences in different colors so that you can easily recognize them and you can even shift/merge the changed data from one file to another just by a click. It's not free though.

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio/TFS can do this via the 'Annotate' function. Otherwise it would depend on your toolset.